# Foreach Question

Tags: c#, foreach

I am trying to use a foreach statement. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
foreach (int item in itemcount)
  {
     label{0}.Text = item.ToString()
  }
```

Where {0} would be the number that is in item.

Is this possible?

Comment: What platfowm do you use ? Winforms ?

Comment: @gor: "We shall welease Bwian" (sorry, couldn't resist the urge) ;o)

Comment: Did u want to do label[item].Text = item.ToString(); ?

Comment: @Fredrik: What about Wodger the wobber? :)

Comment: what is `itemcount`, a count (int), a container or an array?

Comment: @hunter: I'm guessing the OP wants to replace the `{0}` with the index of `item` in the collection, in the same way `string.Format(...)` uses the syntax

Comment: @Tony that's a good guess, but DrRoss has left too much to interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach (int item in itemcount)
{
    Controls[string.Format("label{0}", item.Id)].Text = item.ToString();
}
```

Also, if you need to access properties of the label class you need to cast the left expression to Label class.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is an ASP.NET page then you should be able to find it with `FindControl`:

```
foreach (int item in itemcount)
{
    string name = string.Format("label{0}", item);
    Label label = FindControl(name) as Label;
    if (label != null)
    {
        label.Text = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to programmatically access a variable name, you need to use Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the answer is no. As you do not have access to the iterator the foreach loop is using.

Instead do something like this

```
IList<Label> labels = new ArrayList<Label>();
for(int i = 0;i<labels.count;i++)
{
    labels[i].text = i.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "label" an array? Then you should do this :

```
label[item] = item.ToString();
```

And if label is not an array, probably you should use an array instead of using variable names like label0, label1, ... it would be a lot easier than using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (int item in itemcount)
  {
     label[label.IndexOf(item)].Text = item.ToString()
  }
```

If I need to assume that "label" is a list of labels (List/IList), you've an indexer accessed with [], and lists have an IndexOf method accepting a given existing object in the whole list that returns the index of the "item" - in the list -, as you can check in MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx (IList interface, see methods section).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of throwing answers, depending on `itemcount` type, you could write:

```
Array.ForEach(itemcount, item => label[Convert.ToInt32(item)].Text = item.ToString());
```

if `itemcount` is an `object[]`, or

```
itemcount.ForEach(item => label[Convert.ToInt32(item)].Text = item.ToString());
```

if `itemcount` is a `List<object>`.

Answer (score 0):

While code such as those examples posted earlier does in a strict sense answer the question, it seems like really, really poor design to go down that path.

Depending on your needs, and what framework you are using, you are much better off using some other technique. Arrays of controls are one option; if you're using WPF then this can be achieved quite elegantly using a list that visualizes its elements as labels (you should get that for free, but if not, it'd be trivial to change the control's ItemTemplate - sorry, I don't have any example immediately at hand).